# Angular redirecting me to home page even though entering a valid url

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have a problem with lazy loading of the modules in Angular. I am facing a problem with /products link redirection. When I write localhost:4200/products it opens for a brief second and then automatically redirects me to the home page localhost:4200.  In the home module the children need to have an empty path because they are loaded in the home page.

App-routing.module

```
  const routes: Routes = 
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },{path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/services/services.module').then(m => m.ServicesModule)}];
```

home-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [ { path: '', component: HistoryComponent }}]
```

services-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ServicesComponent,children: [{path: 'products', component:TitleComponent}] }];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to bind in the same const router like that

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'products', loadChildren: () => import('./routes/services/services.module').then(m => m.ServicesModule) }
];
```

services-routing.module:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: ServicesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'products', component: TitleComponent } 
    ]
  }
];
```